# is system context diagram has levels?

Tags: diagram, erd

i heard that context analysis diagram has different levels. is it true...?  i couldn't find it in net. i have seen a DFD has different levels.  like that context diagrams has any levels.?

if yes, please suggest some examples.

Answer (score 0):

A context diagram is actually a level 1 data flow diagram and is purely a diagram of the system and the external entities that interact with it, and the name of the data that is passed from the system to the external entity and back.

Breaking this down into further detail is actually the next data flow diagram, DFD level 2.